# ASW Spark job times out when trying to change multiple values in multiple columns in spark dataframe

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

I am trying to change multiple values in multiple columns as part of my glue job.
Anyway, the function I have written completely times out the job. I have added comments to the function to point out where the issue is.

What is making the glue job not assigning the job to an executor?

```py
    def map_values_in_columns(self, df):
        for k, v in self.value_mapping.items():
            column_name = self.value_mapping[k]['column_name']
            values = self.value_mapping[k]['values']
            df = df.withColumn(column_name,F.col(column_name).cast("string")) 
            for old_value, new_value in values.items():
                old_value = str(old_value)
                new_value = str(new_value)
                df = df.withColumn(column_name, F.when((F.col(column_name)==old_value), new_value).otherwise(F.col(column_name)))
                
          
                # this line results in a progress bar
                df.select(column_name).distinct().show(truncate = False)
            

        # this line here is where my job will hang forever, showing zero sign of life in the logs
        df.select(column_name).distinct().show(truncate = False)
        logger.info("Succesfully mapped values in columns")
        return df
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I solved by homogenising column dtype and dtype of the mapping values, and using df.replace method. Here's the code:

```py
    def map_values_in_columns(self, df):
        for k, v in self.value_mapping.items():
            column_name = self.value_mapping[k]['column_name']
            values = self.value_mapping[k]['values']
            df = df.withColumn(column_name, F.col(column_name).cast("string"))
            new_value_mapping = {}
            for old_value, new_value in values.items():
                str_old_value = str(old_value)
                str_new_value = str(new_value)
                new_value_mapping[str_old_value] = str_new_value
            df = df.replace(new_value_mapping, subset=column_name)
        return df
```